# 3x3 array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to make a 3x3 array in Swift, but the number of rows is always different than what I expect. For example, I thought the code below would make a 3x3 array, but it's actually 9x3 array. Why? And how can I make it 3x3?

```
var NumColumns = 3
var NumRows = 3
var occupied = [[Bool]](count: NumColumns, repeatedValue:[Bool](count: NumRows, repeatedValue:false));
for item in occupied {
    for item in occupied {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is incorrect – you can simply iterate through your array once to show it's structure. It is indeed a 3x3 array, you're iterating within an iteration, giving 9.

Comment: This is 3x3. Just `print(occupied)` and you'll see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop <strike>typo</strike> misuse:

```
for item in occupied {
  for innerItem in item {
    print(innerItem) // prints 9 times
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's looks like you want a 3x3 **matrix** of booleans.

Then you can use the (slightly updated) code provided as example by the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html).

```
struct Matrix {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [Bool]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: false)
    }
    func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

### Example

```
var matrix = Matrix(rows: 3, columns: 3)
matrix[0, 0] = true
print(matrix[0, 0]) // true
```

Comment: It's good to wrap this up in a `struct` if you're using it many times. However, declaring it as a `[[Bool]]` gives you much of the same functionality. For example, you can access a certain value by doing `occupied[0][0]`

Comment: @ColGraff: yes but the `Matrix` struct you can create a matrix where the number of rows/cols is __constant__ and at the same time the value of the cells can be __changed__. With `[[Bool]]` you can't.

Comment: Absolutely, using a `struct` has advantages such as what you've mentioned and more. I was just pointing out that a simple nested `Array` can often serve if you don't need something more complicated.